# How to use php include but not display the page

Tags: php

sendMail.php is showing the whole page when I want just a variable.

Thanks in advance

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include 'index.php';
$senderEmail = $_SESSION['uname'];
$recipientEmail = 'philip@scriver.net'; 
$message = filterInput($_POST['message']);
$subject = filterInput($_POST['Subject']);
$attach1 = filterInput($_POST['attach1']);

if(sendEmailWithAttachments($recipientEmail,$senderEmail,$subject,$message,$attach1))...
```

Comment: Why do you have this `$_SESSION['uname'] = $row['email'];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include is not for setting a variable, it gets all the content of the file you include even html, so yes it will display on your screen. If you want to get a variable, you have  more options:
-Store in database and get by SQL query
-Send it via POST or GET request

You might also want to store your php code as separated from your html as possible. So you might store codes you use at multiple locations in one php file that contains no html at all, and include that file only, so it won't display any html content on your screen. Though for sending a value I would stick to the first 2 option